# Can I use the ROC curve to compare two distributions?

Tags: probability, distributions, roc

The ROC curve for two distributions $F$ and $G$ can be defined as

$$\mbox{ROC}(u) = {F}(G^{-1}(u)),$$
for $u \in (0,1)$. So, if $F=G$, then $\mbox{ROC}(u) = u$. Can I use this property to compare the two distributions $F$ and $G$? For example, by checking deviations from the identity function?

Comment: Can you explain more about how you're obtaining/observing F and/or G? Are you comparing two ecdfs or one ecdf and one theoretical cdf? Certainly if F is an ecdf and G a continuous theoretical cdf, any number of measures of deviation from a straight line would be usable as goodness of fit tests (and at least some of them would correspond to well known tests).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

See Dana Quade's [pair chart](https://onlinelibrary.wiley.com/doi/abs/10.1111/j.1467-9574.1973.tb00206.x) which relates to the Wilcoxon-Mann-Whitney two-sample rank-sum test.